# Attempted to read or write protected memory .... in Silverlight Windows Phone 8.1 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio 2013 project for Windows Phone 8.1 in Silverlight. I recently update Visual Studio to Update 4. After updating I am getting error on code ListPickerFlyout with **Attempted to read or write protected memory.This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.**

Above happen only when I run the project and Windows Phone Emulator starts. But when I close visual studio and start there will be no error. First I repair Windows Emulator 8.1 installation but still did not help. So I Modify Visual Studio 2013 by remove Windows Phone SDK 8.0 which remove SDK and Emulator. Then re-install it but same error.

But when I run app in emulator there is no error and it runs smoothly. So I wanted to know how to resolve it and it is critical error, will it make any issue in future.

[image]

More on this I created new blank project and added ListPickerFlyout and Once I run it start giving me same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to somebody

There is issue with XAML Code When I remove ItemSource and SelectedItem attribute, error goes away. It seems I was not doing proper ItemSource and SelectedItem properly.

Hope it may help somebody